# Unity gives strange errors when i try to build my project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build, unity-editor

Unity gives me these strange errors for some reason when i try to build my project. I do not know why it gives me these errors, when they should've been given earlier. I've tried restarting unity, deleting the "plugins" folder, deleting the .sln files and putting the build folder on a different folder. How can i fix these strange errors??

**here's the code unity keeps giving me errors from, if that helps anything:** https://paste.myst.rs/lwj5nsm1

**And here's the errors unity gave me:**

Assets\LevelGenerator\Scripts\Editor\LevelEditor.cs(9,30): error CS0115: 'GeneratorEditor.OnInspectorGUI()': no suitable method found to override

Assets\LevelGenerator\Scripts\Editor\LevelEditor.cs(7,48): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Editor' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Assets\LevelGenerator\Scripts\Editor\LevelEditor.cs(6,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CustomEditorAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\LevelGenerator\Scripts\Editor\LevelEditor.cs(6,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CustomEditor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 5 errors
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ca] in :0
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in :0
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

Comment: Hm in general anything inside a folder called `Editor` as well as the entire namespace `UnityEditor` are completely stripped of during the build process .. so yeah you shouldn't get these errors actually. Are you using Assembly Definitions? If so make sure that only the editor is enabled as valid target platform for the editor scripts assembly

Comment: Aren't those types of errors because some runtime code is depending on editor code that is stripped in a build. But when run in Unity there is no errors because that dependency is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is used for the editor, and therefore should not be included in the build result.What I do to solve this, I create a "DONOTCOMPILETHIS" build directive that I add to the player Settings.
[PlayerSetting DLG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XSTj.png)

and finaly in your code add :

```
using UnityEngine;

#if !DONOTCOMPILETHIS

using UnityEditor;

using UnityEditor.IMGUI.Controls;


[CustomEditor(typeof(CGameTower)), CanEditMultipleObjects]

public class CBoundRectEditor : Editor

{

    private BoxBoundsHandle m_BoundsHandle = new BoxBoundsHandle();


    ...

}

#endif
```